# Update an order afterwards

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2

Have to update an order afterwards cause the client can choose a retail partner.

```
<form method="post" name="submitOrder" style="width: 100%" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/update-cart">
    {{ redirectInput('s/partner?number=' ~ number) }}
    {{ csrfInput() }}

    <input type="text" id="retailPartner"
           name="fields[orderCommercePartner][]"
           value="0">

    <input type="submit" 
           class="a-button  a-button--black  a-button--bold js-chooseThisPartner"
           style="margin-bottom: 40px;"
           value="{{ 'Choose this partner' | t }}">
</form>
```

That's my form I fill the value `fields[orderCommercePartner][]` via JS and it's filled.

But the order is not updated. Any Ideas what goes wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Orders can not be updated after they are completed. The only way around this at the moment is if a plugin used it's own controller action to update the order.

Please submit a feature request here: https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues